# How to search for file in folder containing specific text and rename that file in Python

Tags: python, filenames

I'm trying to find a filename that contains specific text I pass using a list. I have been able to find the files, but I cannot seem to rename them. I'm unsure what I'm doing wrong so any help will be greatly appreciated. Pretty new at python, so just trying to learn with some simple tasks.

```
from os import rename, listdir
import fnmatch

i = 0
divisions = ['BAT','FAB','HIN','OFA','SBY','VAL',
             'FRE','JEF','OLA','SPR','WEB','CTV',
             'MOB','PET','SWN','DEN','GRE','MTJ',
             'ROS','SXB','DWT','HAI','OAK','RPB','TUL']

divs = listdir('.')
ending = " Financials.xlsx"

for div in divs:
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(div, divisions[i]):
        rename(div, divisions[i] + ending)
    i += 1
```

Comment: What goes wrong? Does the `if` find files? Does the rename run without error? Since we don't have your filenames, its hard to guess what the problem is. Is there a standard format for files in that directory? You could run some tests, for instance `fnmatch.fnmatch("BAT Financials.xlsx", "BAT")` doesn't match.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. So the script runs without errors, but the filenames are not changed. For example the file name containing "BAT" is "BAT Financials 2020.xls". I am trying to change it to "BAT Financials.xlsx". But some other files names contain other text in them, such as: "2020", "KPI", "October". They all contain a tag for where they came from like "BAT" but I want to change them all to be uniform like"BAT Financials.xlsx" so [Divisions] + ending. I'm not sure if I'm even feeding it correctly though. My theory was to find a filename with a matching division string and then change it.

Comment: Great! You have a couple of problems with the code, one of them is that you don't include wildcards in fnmatch so nothing will match. Since you know the exact names of the files you want, fnmatch isn't needed. And you for loop compares the wrong things. I'll write up an answer.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much @tdelaney! Yeah I figured it was something with the wildcard, but I thought it might be my for loop that was just not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code. First, the `fnmatch` pattern needs a wildcard to match file name. Second, you are only comparing 1 `divisions` value per filename, when you need to spin through all of them until you find a match. Fixing those gives you the following (I renamed a couple of values because having a thing called "divisions" while the file list is "divs" was a bit confusing)

```
from os import rename, listdir
from fnmatch import fnmatch

divisions = ['BAT','FAB','HIN','OFA','SBY','VAL',
             'FRE','JEF','OLA','SPR','WEB','CTV',
             'MOB','PET','SWN','DEN','GRE','MTJ',
             'ROS','SXB','DWT','HAI','OAK','RPB','TUL']

# build (division name, fnmatch pattern) for each division
patterns = [(division, f"{division} Financials*.xlsx") for division in divisions]

filenames = listdir('.')

for filename in filenames:
    for division, pattern in patterns:
        if fnmatch(filename, pattern):
            rename(filename, f"{division} Financials.xlsx")
            break
```

If you want to limit that to 2020 specifically, the pattern would change. In fact, you wouldn't need fnmatch at all because you know the exact file name.

```
from os import rename, listdir

divisions = ['BAT','FAB','HIN','OFA','SBY','VAL',
             'FRE','JEF','OLA','SPR','WEB','CTV',
             'MOB','PET','SWN','DEN','GRE','MTJ',
             'ROS','SXB','DWT','HAI','OAK','RPB','TUL']
filename_map = dict(f"{division} Financials 2020.xlsx":f"{division} Finanacials.xlsx" 
    for division in divisions)

filenames = listdir('.')

for filename in filenames:
    mapped = filename_map.get(filename)
    if mapped:
        rename(filename, mapped)
```

Comment: You rock! If I wanted to just use the fnmatch pattern on the {division} would I just omit the "Financials.xlsx". Since I would like to capture any file name that contains that word.

Comment: Yes. You can open the python shell and practice patterns like `fnmatch("BAT something.else", "BAT *")` and see what happens.